# how to launch IE with multiple parameters in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

This is my script

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2
```

I modify coz I found out that `%*` would enable multiple parameters

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com?a%*=1&b=2%*
```

or this

```
@echo off
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com?%*a=1&b=2%*
```

But neither works. What m i lacking?

Comment: What are you passing in as parameters? What do they look like? `%*` means "put all parameters here", so I'm pretty sure that's not what you want in your URL.

Comment: Actually, I got it. `start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com?a=1^&b=2` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com?a=1^&b=2